# Manipulating control accessed with "byId" has no effect

Tags: sapui5

I have a sample of icons in a `HBox` in an XML view as below:

```xml
<m:HBox>
  <core:Icon src="sap-icon://show" color="#007bff" id="test1"  press="onPressView" />
  <core:Icon src="sap-icon://edit" color="#007bff" id="test2" press="onPressEdit" />
  <core:Icon src="sap-icon://print" color="#007bff" id="test3" press="onPressPrint" />
</m:HBox>
```

In controller to set visible `false`, I am doing as:

```js
let testIcon1 = this.getview().byId('test1');
testIcon1.setVisible(false);
```

But this isn't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably accessing a template control instead of the actual rendered one. If you inspect the element in the devtools, see if the ID of the rendered control (Icon) has the suffix `__clone<n>`.

Since such ID suffixes are generated by the framework, accessing cloned controls via `byId` should be avoided. There are many alternative solutions in such cases. A general good solution is to separate views from the controller by binding the control properties (e.g. `visible`) and manipulating those properties from the model.