# In SAPUI5, the button text from my IconTabFilter is not changing with the .settext?

Tags: button, sapui5

I already spent hours looking for this solution here and on google, but to no success. I would love if someone could help me with this problem.

I have a button that, when pressed, expands my data to show more information. When pressed again, it collapses the data. I want to change the text value of the button depending on which state it is (expand or collapse).

this is my view.xml:

```
<IconTabBar
        id="idIconTabBarNoIcons"
        items="{/Sheet1}"
        class="sapUiResponsiveContentPadding">
        <items>
           <IconTabFilter text="{category_title}" key="info">
              <Toolbar class="toolbar_boarder">
                 <ToolbarSpacer/>
                 <Button id="IdExpandButton" tooltip="Additional Information" text="Expand" type="Transparent" press="onPressExpand" />
```

And this is my controller.js:

```
        onPressExpand: function(oEvent){
        debugger;
        var controls = this.getView().getControlsByFieldGroupId("hideShowElements");
        var ExpandButtonText = this.getView().byId("IdExpandButton").getText();
        var panel = this.getView().getControlsByFieldGroupId("idPanel");
        if(ExpandButtonText == "Expand"){
            for(var i=0; i<controls.length;i++){
                controls[i].setVisible(false);
            }
            this.getView().byId("IdExpandButton").setText("Collapse");
            this.getView().byId("IdExpandButton").setType("Accept");

        }else{
            for(var i=0; i<controls.length;i++){
                controls[i].setVisible(true);
            }
            this.getView().byId("IdExpandButton").setText("Expand");
            this.getView().byId("IdExpandButton").setType("Transparent");
        }
```

There is more to the code, but this is the part that matters.

The text keeps does not visually change (it keeps "Extend"), even though the code is working in expanding/collapsing the information (so I guess the text is changing internally, but not showing into the html page).

Does anyone have an idea why the .setText property is not changing the text in the button?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Manipulating control accessed with "byId" has no effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61674679/manipulating-control-accessed-with-byid-has-no-effect)

Comment: How can I make use of models insetead of byID? I checked the sample code provided by the link, but even then I could not understand. Also, I inspected the element on devtools and could not see the suffix __clone<n> . I am sorry for my ignorance, I am new to coding.

Comment: 1) Why are you binding `ìtems` on the IconTabBar? Do you have an undefined number of tabs? 2) Why are you implementing this expand/collapse behavior when the control you are using (IconTabBar/IconTabFilter) already provide this functionality?

Comment: Items refer to the content showed on the page (for the tab, it gets the "Category_title" to fill up categories which user can click and show different content). The number of tabs grows according to new categories being added. The expand/collapse behavior acts on the content itself, showing more or less information of the contents of a category.

Comment: As @BoghyonHoffmann mentioned, you are most probably accessing the template, from which items are created, and not the items themselves. I would suggest reading more about [aggregation binding](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/topic/97830de2d7314e93b5c1ee3878a17be9) first

Answer (score -1):

thank you very much for helping. Special thanks to Petar D. and Boghyon Hoffmann.

I read through the materials your provided and learned a lot more about controls and ids.

I solved my problem getting the global id from my button created by SAPUI5 automatically using: oEvent.getSource().getId();
Then I could change the text using that ID.

Comment: OK let me get this straight. `oEvent.getSource()` is your button. Then you get the ID of the button and with the ID of the button you get the button? This seems far from optimal. Also you could just change the data of the underlying model without accessing the control directly.